# using HtmlUnit behind proxy

Tags: java, proxy, htmlunit

I'm trying to use HtmlUnit behind a proxy :

```
public class App {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "172.23.232.10");
    System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8080");

    final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://www.google.com");
    System.out.println(page.getTitleText());

     }
}
```

And I had a connection Time out exception

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to www.google.com:80 [www.google.com/172.217.16.196] failed: Connection timed out: connect
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:158)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353)
```

Is there a solution to specify the proxy properties for HtmlUnit (browser)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
ProxyConfig proxyConfig = new ProxyConfig("172.23.232.10", 8080);
webClient.getOptions().setProxyConfig(proxyConfig);
```

You have more information [here](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/WebClientOptions.html#setProxyConfig(com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ProxyConfig)).

Answer (score 2):

**you can do `proxy` like this:**

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_45, proxyHost, proxyPort);
```